# C++ large 2D Array access violation

Tags: c++

So I have a program that I have created for finding an optimal binary search tree and it works great when the data set is around 100 but when I try and use a data set >1000 I get an access violation when weight[i][i] = frequency[i]; is called inside the computeOBST function. I'm not sure if that data set is to large or what. I'm stuck and not sure what else to try any help would be great.

```
int* keys = new int[numKeys];                   
int* keyLevel = new int[numKeys];               
int* frequency = new int[numKeys];              
int** weight = new int*[numKeys+2];             
int** cost = new int*[numKeys];                 
int** root = new int*[numKeys];                 

void allocateArraySpace(int n){
    int i;
    // Allocate space for the 2-dim'l cost array
    for (i = 0; i < numKeys + 2; i++) {
        cost[i] = new int[numKeys + 2];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < numKeys + 1; i++) {
        keyLevel[i] = numKeys + 1;
    }

    // Allocate space for the 2-dim'l root array
    for (i = 0; i < numKeys + 1; i++) {
        root[i] = new int[numKeys + 1];
    }

     //Allocate space for the 2-dim'l weight array
    for (i = 0; i <= numKeys + 2; i++) {
        weight[i] = new int[numKeys + 2];
    }

}

void computeOBST(int n) {
    numKeys = n;
    int i, j, k, h, m;

    allocateArraySpace(numKeys);

    //creating weight matrix
    for (int i = 1; i <= numKeys + 1; i++)
    {
        weight[i][i] = frequency[i];
        for (j = i + 1; j <= numKeys; j++)
            weight[i][j] = weight[i][j - 1] + frequency[j];
    }

    //
    for (i = 1; i <= numKeys; i++)
        for (j = i + 1; j <= numKeys + 1; j++)
            cost[i][j] = INT_MAX;

    //
    for (i = 1; i <= numKeys + 1; i++)
        cost[i][i - 1] = 0;

    //
    for (i = 1; i <= numKeys; i++) {
        cost[i][i] = weight[i][i];
        root[i][i] = i;
    }
```

Comment: This sort of 2D array is often a performance killer because it is built up of N+1 completely distinct arrays all in their own little blocks of memory and could be anywhere in storage. The result is poor [spatial locality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) and increased likelihood of cache misses, slowing down your program as it waits for access to memory that could have already been cached.

Answer (score 4):

`cost` is only of size `numKeys`, but in your loop in `allocateArraySpace` you access `numKeys+2` elements of it?  There are similar issues for the other arrays.

Remember that arrays in C++ are 0-based, so if you do `cost = new int *[numKeys]`, then `cost[numKeys-1]` is okay but `cost[numKeys]` and `cost[numKeys+1]` are out of bounds.

Answer (score 2):

> `int* frequency = new int[numKeys]`

then

> `for (int i = 1; i <= numKeys + 1; i++) { weight[i][i] = frequency[i]; ...`

You will go out of bound. *Undefined Behavior*. It happens that this UB for small values does not result in a segmentation fault, while it does so for high values of `numKeys`.

This is just an example, you have the same error at many placrs. Check again all your loops and array bounds and set the correct limits.

In general, when you span an array of size `numKeys`, you scan it in the following way (remember C arrays are zero-based):

```
for (int i = 0; i < numKeys; i++) // first index is 0, last is numKeys-1
```

Comment: ok that makes sense. What would you suggest is the best way to deal with the segmentation fault?

Comment: Nothing else than removing it completely, by avoiding out-of-bounds everywhere. In general, `for (int i = 0; i < numKeys; i++) ` when you access an array of size `numKeys`